# Why is a left parenthesis being escaped in this Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using an HTML sanitizing whitelist code found here:
http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html

I needed to add the "font" tag as an additional tag to match, so I tried adding this condition after the `<img` tag check

```
if (tagname.StartsWith("<font"))
{
    // detailed <font> tag checking
    // Non-escaped expression (for testing in a Regex editor app)
    // ^<font(\s*size="\d{1}")?(\s*color="((#[0-9a-f]{6})|(#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)")?(\s*face="(Arial|Courier New|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)")?\s*?>$
    if (!IsMatch(tagname, @"<font
                            (\s*size=""\d{1}"")?
                            (\s*color=""((#[0-9a-f]{6})|(#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)"")?
                            (\s*face=""(Arial|Courier New|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)"")?
                             \s*?>"))
    {
        html = html.Remove(tag.Index, tag.Length);
    }
}
```

Aside from the condition above, my code is almost identical to the code in the page I linked to. When I try to test this in C#, it throws an exception saying "`Not enough )'s`". I've counted the parenthesis several times and I've run the expression through a few online Javascript-based regex testers and none of them seem to tell me of any problems.

Am I missing something in my Regex that is causing a parenthesis to escape? What do I need to do to fix this?

**UPDATE**
After a lot of trial and error, I remembered that the `#` sign is a comment in regexes. The key to fixing this is to escape the `#` character. In case anyone else comes across the same problem, I've included my fix (just escaping the `#` sign)

```
if (tagname.StartsWith("<font"))
{
    // detailed <font> tag checking
    // Non-escaped expression (for testing in a Regex editor app)
    // ^<font(\s*size="\d{1}")?(\s*color="((#[0-9a-f]{6})|(#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)")?(\s*face="(Arial|Courier New|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)")?\s*?>$
    if (!IsMatch(tagname, @"<font
                            (\s*size=""\d{1}"")?
                            (\s*color=""((\#[0-9a-f]{6})|(\#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)"")?
                            (\s*face=""(Arial|Courier\sNew|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)"")?
                             \s*?>"))
    {
        html = html.Remove(tag.Index, tag.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your update only applies if the IgnorePatternWhitespace option is specified ... which is in the IsMatch code I asked about without a reply... i.e. you didn't show us the code that caused the problem.

Comment: As an aside: your regex will not match a font tag with the attributes in a different order, like <font color="red" size="2">

Comment: I'm OK with the attributes not being matched in a different order. The HTML editor control I'm using will only generate the <font> tag in the order I am testing for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IsMatch Method is using the option `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, that allows you to put comments inside the regular expressions, so you have to scape the # chatacter, otherwise it will be interpreted as a comment.

```
if (!IsMatch(tagname,@"<font(\s*size=""\d{1}"")?
    (\s*color=""((\#[0-9a-f]{6})|(\#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)"")?
    (\s*face=""(Arial|Courier New|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)"")?
    \s?>"))
{
    html = html.Remove(tag.Index, tag.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the regex.  I would try isolating the problem by removing pieces of the regex until the problem goes away and then focus on the part that causes the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure it is anything to do with the Regex - it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me... what version of the .NET framework are you using, and what is the *exact* exception?

Also - what does you `IsMatch` method look like? is this just a pass-thru to `Regex.IsMatch`?

[update] The problem is that the OP's example code didn't show they are using the IgnorePatternWhitespace regex option; with this option it doesn't work; without this option (i.e. as presented) the code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Download Chris Sells [Regex Designer](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#regexd).  Its a great free tool for testing .NET regex's.

I'm not sure this regex is going to do what you want because it depends on the order of the attributes matching what you have in the regex. If for example `face="Arial"` preceeded `size="5"` then `face=` wouldn't match.

There are some escaping problems in your regex.  You need to escape your `"` with `\`  You need to escape your `#` with `\`  You need to use `\s` in Courier New instead of just the space.  You need to use the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` and `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase options`.

```
<font
(\s+size=\"\d{1}\")?
(\s+color=\"((\#[0-9a-f]{6})|(\#[0-9a-f]{3})|red|green|blue|black|white)\")?
(\s+face=\"(Arial|Courier\sNew|Garamond|Georgia|Tahoma|Verdana)\")?
```

The `#` characters are what was causing the exception with the somewhat misleading missing ) message.

Comment: The order of the attributes will always be the same for me because of the text editor control I'm using. I don't need to escape my " because of the @ sign. That's a good catch with "courier new." I didn't see that one.